# Does Hadoop create multiple copies of input files, one copy per node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If I wish to copy a file from a local directory to a HDFS, do I need to physically copy the file on each Hadoop node?
Or if I use the hadoop dfs command, Hadoop will internally create a copy of this file on each node?

Am I correct to assume that each node needs to have a copy of the file?

Answer (score 4):

When you will copy the file (any data) `Hadoop` (HDFS) will store it on any `Datanode` and metadata information will be stored on `Namenode`. The replication of the file (data) will be taken care by `Hadoop`, you need not to copy it multiple times.

You can use of the below command to copy files from local to HDFS

```
hdfs dfs -put <source> <destination>
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <source> <destination>
```

The replication factor configuration is stored in `hdfs-site.xml` file.

> Am I correct to assume that each node needs to have a copy of the file?

This is not necessarily true. HDFS creates replica as per the configuration found in the `hdfs-site.xml` file. The default for the replication is 3.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah hadoop distributed file system replicates data in minimum 3 datanodes. But nowadays trend is on spark which is also run on top of hadoop. And this is 100 times faster than hadoop.

spark http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to copy the file from local machine to every node in the cluster.

You could use client utiles like `hadoop fs` or `hadoop dfs` commands to do so.

It is not necessary that your file will be copied to all the nodes in the cluster, the number of replications is controlled by the `dfs.replication` property from the `hdfs-site.xml` configuration file, where its default value is 3, means that 3 copies of your file be stored across the cluster on some random nodes.

Please refer the more details below,

- `hadoop dfs` command first contacts the `Namenode` with the given
  files's details.
- The `Namenode` computes the number of blocks that the file has to
  splitted according to the block size configured in `hdfs-site.xml`
- The `Namenode` returns the list of chosen `Datanodes` for every
  computed block of the given file. This count of `Datanodes` in every
  list is equal to the replication factor configured in the
  `hdfs-site.xml`
- Then the hadoop client starts storing every blocks of the file to the
  given `Datanode` through `Hadoop Streaming`.
- For each block, the hadoop client just prepares the `data pipe line`
  in which all chosen `Datanodes` chosen to store the block are formed
  as a `Data queue`.
- The hadoop client just copies the current block only to the first
  `Datanode` in the queue.
- Upon completion of the copy, the first Datanode cascades the block to
  second Datanode in the Queue and so on.
- All the block details of the files and the details of Datanodes which
  have the copy of them are maintained in `Namenode's metadata`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to copy files manually to all nodes.
Hadoop will take care of distributing data to different nodes.

you can use simple commands to upload data to HDFS

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal </path/to/local/file> </path/to/hdfs>
```

OR

```
hadoop fs -put </path/to/local/file> </path/to/hdfs>
```

You can read more how data is internally written on HDFS here : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html

You can also download file from HDFS to local filessytem wothout manually copying files from each datanode using command:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal </path/to/hdfs/file> </path/to/local>
```

OR

```
hadoop fs -get  </path/to/hdfs/file> </path/to/local>
```